# How to cluster lat/lng data with restrictions on max distance between points and max number of points per cluster

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have a set of lat/long coordinates spread out across a city (about 1000). I'd like to create clusters with this data following some strict rules:

1. No cluster can have more than X data points in it (possibly 8, but this can change)
2. No cluster can contain two data points with more than Xkm between them (possibly 1km, but this can change too)
3. There can be clusters with one single point
4. No specific number of clusters need to be created

I've tried doing this using AgglomerativeClustering from sklearn, using the following code:

```py
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering

cluster = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=None, affinity='euclidean', linkage='complete', distance_threshold=0.01)
cluster.fit_predict(arr)
```

The issue here is that I'm not fulfilling items 1,2 or 3 above, only item 4.

I'd like to have a clustering algorithm where I'm able to set those parameters and have it run the most efficient clustering possible (ie: least number of clusters that respect all of items 1,2,3 and 4).

Is there any way this could be done with sklearn or any other imported clustering algo or would one have to build this manually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Write your own.

A simple approach would be to use agglomerative clustering (the real one, e.g., from scipy; the sklearn version is too limited) to get the *full* merge history for *complete linkage*. Then begin processing merges bottom-up if they satisfy your two requirements: the linkage is the maximum distance, and if the cluster becomes too large then you stop merging.

Beware that the result will, however, quite unbalanced. My guess is that you want as few clusters as possible to cover your data with the maximum radius and occupacy. Then your problem is likely closer to *set cover*. Finding the optimum result on such problems is usually NP hard, so you'll have to accept using an approximation. I'd go with a greedy strategy and then iterative refinement by local search.